# Unit test an AngularJS document ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, unit-testing

I'm writing an AngularJS application and I'm searching for a way to unit test every single aspect.

In this particular case, I need to unit test a custom directive which I've written that represents a control.

The directive can be found here:

```
var officeButton = angular.module('OfficeButton', []);

officeButton.directive('officeButton', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            isDefault: '@',
            isDisabled: '@',
            control: '=',
            label: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="button-wrapper" data-ng-click="onClick()">' +
                    '<a href="#" class="button normal-button">' +
                      '<span>{{label}}</span>' +
                    '</a>' +
                  '</div>',
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            var event = this;

            var api = {

                changeLabel: function(label) {
                    $scope.label = label;
                },

                enable: function() {
                    $scope.isDisabled = false;
                },

                disable: function() {
                    $scope.isDisabled = true;
                },

                setAsDefault: function() {
                    $scope.isDefault = true;
                },

                removeDefault: function() {
                    $scope.isDefault = false;
                }
            };

            event.onClick = function() {
                if (typeof $scope.control.onClick === 'function') { $scope.control.onClick(); }
            };

            $.extend($scope.control, api);

            function Init() {
                if ($scope.isDefault === 'true') { $scope.isDefault = true; }
                else { $scope.isDefault = false; }
            }

            Init();
        }],

        link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {

            scope.$watch('isDefault', function(value) {
                if (value === 'true' || value) { $('a', element).addClass('button-default'); }
                else { $('a', element).removeClass('button-default'); }
            });

            scope.onClick = function() { controller.onClick(); }
        }
    }
});
```

This directive can be called by using the following HTML snippet:

```
<office-button label="Office Web Controls" control="buttonController"></office-button>
```

Now, this directive exposes an API which functions such as `changeLabel`, `enable`, `disable`, ....

Now, those functions are not defined on the load of the application, meaning if at the bottom of my HTML I call the following code:

$scope.buttonController.changeLabel('Office Web Controls for Web Applications Directive Demo');

It will throw an error because the `changeLabel()` method is not defined.

In order to make it function, I need to wrap those calls in an `angular.ready` function, such as:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    $scope.buttonController.changeLabel('Office Web Controls for Web Applications Directive Demo');
});
```

Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bze6GFcQNfjljcxgAua2?p=info) for your information.

Now, I'm writing unit tests using Jasmine, and here's what I have for the moment:

```
describe('Office Web Controls for Web Applications - Button Testing.', function() {
    // Provides all the required variables to perform Unit Testing against the 'button' directive.
    var $scope, element;
    var buttonController = {};

    // Loads the directive 'OfficeButton' before every test is being executed.
    beforeEach(module('OfficeButton'));

    // Build the element so that it can be called.
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        // Sets the $scope variable so that it can be used in the future.
        $scope = $rootScope;
        $scope.control = buttonController;

        element = angular.element('<office-button control="buttonController"></office-button>');
        $compile(element)($scope);
        $scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('Should expose an API with certain functions.', function() {
    });
});
```

Now, in the `it` function, I would like to test if the `$scope.control` does expose the API as defined in the directive.

The problem is that the page needs to be ready before the API is available.

Any tought on how to change the code or how to unit test this correctly?

Comment: Anybody who have toughts on this because I'm lost in this story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the issue, it was just a wrong configuration on the unit test.

When using this code:

```
$scope.control = buttonController;
element = angular.element('<office-button control="buttonController"></office-button>');
```

I must change the element to:

```
$scope.control = buttonController;
element = angular.element('<office-button control="control"></office-button>');
```